# Vb .net Chart Spline Vertical orientation with a logaritmic X-axis get Exception

Tags: .net, charts

I am facing a big problem trying to plot a vertical "Spline" on my vb .net chart with a logarithmic scale on x.

I am needing to plot it vertically, because it's intended to be used to graph a **depth vr gas** relation, which can go from 0 to 1.000.000 value.

I have browsed a lot  to check if the the **rotation of the X and Y axis was possible** on the vb chart, with not success.

When I try to set the X axis to **Logarithmic**, is just get a exception at runtime.

**Is this possible? Thanks**

[image: Net chart Spline - Log x (On Designer)]

Answer (score 0):

Well, just found the solution to this problem. The logaritmic axis gona throw the exception if it's **not holding any data-points**, or some one of them have a **value of 0**. At desing time, values are simulated diferent than 0 so no exception it's throwd there.